# How to handle pdf file while automating Mobile web in Android device using Appium?

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, browser-automation

I was trying to automate mobile web in android device, using **Appium**. While I click on a button it open a pdf file and ask to open with any native app which are installed in Android. So, in this scenario I want to make sure the correct pdf file is **opened/downloaded**. 
So, please let me know how can I automate this scenario.

Comment: Can you describe what you are expecting to test ??

Comment: I want to automate the following scenario in android device:
1. Click on a link.
2. It will open a pdf file with other installed pdf viewer application

Comment: post what you have already tried please.

Answer (score -1):

since it is native app you can inspect the pages of the pdf through appium inspector and you can verify the text in the

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33719788)